# Why can the tree view of MC have a folder as root in the version for PowerShell but not the version for Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, midnight-commander, tree-view

MC (Midnight Commander) has versions for both Linux Bash and Windows PowerShell. It has tree view but the feature seems different.

In order to open a tree view with a folder as root of the tree on the version for PowerShell:

- Show both panels as file listing
- Navigate to a folder
- Turn on the tree view
- Now the root of the tree view is the folder

However, in the version for Linux, it's not possible to do so, the root of the tree view is always the root dir (the slash).

A folder can be tree root (in orange colour) in the version for PowerShell:
[image]

But no folder can be tree root (in orange colour) in the version for Bash, navigating to a folder first doesn't work:
[image]

**Is it possible to use a directory as tree root in the version for Bash?**

Comment: Idle guess: Could it have to do with file systems? Is that behavior the same on NTFS, BTRFS and ext4?